# Python3 problem with recalling a function

Tags: python-3.x, function

i have a part of code presented below and my issue is when i try to call `bet_definer(point, digit_option, bet_team, m, url)`(i marked it below in code) nothing happens, but it's supposed to run `bet_definer` part again a few times. What do i do wrong?

```
def bet_definer(point, digit_option, bet_team, url, m):
    for i in range(0, 10):
        if re.search(r'\+', str(bet_team)):
            digit_option_changed = int(digit_option) + int(i)
        else:
            digit_option_changed = int(digit_option) - int(i)
            if digit_option_changed < 1:
                print("menshe 1")
                if i < 9:
                    if m < 4:
                        time.sleep(5)
                        m += 1
                        bet_definer(point, digit_option, bet_team, url, m)
                    else:
                        print("значение выросло, не подходит")
                        break
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
        pyautogui.write(str(digit_option_changed) + '.5')
        time.sleep(random.random())
        pyautogui.moveTo(663, 208)
        time.sleep(random.random())
        if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(663, 208, (103, 103, 103)):
            if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(point[0], point[1], ((56, 216, 120) or (255, 255, 255))):
                pyautogui.moveTo(273, 448)
                time.sleep(random.random())
                if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(301, 451, (80, 80, 80)):
                    time.sleep(2)
                    m = 0
                    bet_definer(point, digit_option, bet_team, url, m)
                else:
                    pyautogui.click(x=point[0], y=point[1])
                    print('nashel')
                    match = True
                    match_check(point, digit_option, bet_team, match, r, url)
                    break
            elif i == 9:
                match = False
                match_check(point, digit_option, bet_team, match, r, url)
        else:
            pyautogui.click(x=663, y=208, button='left', clicks=5, interval=0.5)
def match_check(point, digit_option, bet_team, match, r, url):
    if match:
        time.sleep(2)
        make_bet(m, r)
    else:
        print('oshibka')
        if r < 4:
            r += 1
            time.sleep(5)
            print(f"ищу снова {r} раз")
            bet_definer(point, digit_option, bet_team, m, url) #here is the problem
        else:
            print("попытки без результата")
            return
```

Comment: What do you find when you use a debugger to observe the execution of the code?

Comment: The code under `def bet_definer` isn't indented correctly.

Comment: it's kinda typo here, so It's not a problem